# Chrome doesn't prompt to use a local certificate after setting up client certificate authentication on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, authentication

I have used [this guide](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/apache-ssl-client-auth) to set up client certificate authentication on Apache.

I verified my certificate using the `openssl verify` directive (it's valid), I also successfully imported the PFX file into my macOS Keychain and set it to "Trust always".

Additionally, I created a new `.htaccess` document in the `/admin` directory of my website and filled it with two lines:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10
```

The idea is of course to limit access to the admin panel via the client certificate.

Now, when I access my `/admin` page in Chrome, I get this:
[image]

So, things *seem* to work. The issue is, that the browser does not prompt me in any way to provide the local certificate I imported in Keychain, which prevents me from actually accessing the `/admin` resource.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome doesn't support post-handhsake authentication, that is, renegotiating SSL and sending a client certificate  when the connection is already established, because (from the Chrome bugreport page)

> Post-handshake authentication has a mess of security, semantics, and DoS issues. (...) Some spec work is needed to make it defined in HTTP/1.1 at all and, more importantly, explicitly undefined in HTTP/2 in favor of a multiplexing-friendly solution (...)

In Firefox, you can turn it on, but it is not enabled by default, for the same reasons Chrome does not implement it.

You can check the bug reports ([Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1511989), [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=911653)) for additional info.

I think what you can do is to set the `SSLVerifyClient` to `optional`, move it to the `VirtualHost` level (with any `SSL*` directives, so the certificate will be requested during handshake), and require the presence of a certificate in the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
AuthName "Admin resource"
AuthType Basic
Require ssl-verify-client
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the sources, makes sense. I applied the suggestions you mentioned: I edited my .htaccess and added the SSL directive to my default.conf file within the VirtualHost block. Now the page simply says: Forbidden, You don't have permission to access this resource. Still no prompt. Tricky stuff.